# Multiple lines selection with ctrl

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, selection, multipleselection

Hello guys today i woke up with very weird feeling that something is wrong with my vscode, I can't select multiple lines with just CTRL+click, only using multiple carets. Is it normal? how to avoid that? its pretty usefull to just quickly select some random divs element and delete them all by one backspace click.

Isn't it a standard in text editors to do it only with ctrl?

Sorry for such a trivial question, I have no other place to ask about it and get an answer

Comment: In the selection menu make sure you've selected "Switch to Ctrl+Click for Multi-Cursor". Otherwise the shortcut will be Alt+Click

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge Thanks man. But lol can't believe i worked for weeks in vscode and didnt realize the multi selection with only ctrl doesnt work like in Ms Word for example. Do you know if its possible to select multiple lines and with only one caret finally?